# Find keywords in a datatable in R

Tags: r

I have a data table in R that has names numbers and emails

1. john smith   131234123412     email address
2. sally smith      2314423423    email address

They are separated by column

I want to be able to search for every instances where "john" is mentioned and then return the whole row.

Comment: have you looked at `grepl` ?

Comment: @Michael - if one of the answers was correct and helpful, could you please accept it, so that it no longer appears as unanswered?

Answer (score 1):

It's really helpful for people wanting to help you to have a reproducible example - here's a link to explain how to do this easily: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Without a reproducible example, it's a bit difficult to be exact with an answer, but here's something to nudge you in the right direction:

```
df[grepl("john", df$first_name), ]
```

I've named the data table `df` here and the column containing the name "john" as `first_name`.

'grepl' will search the `first_name` column for the word `john`. The data frame will then be filtered to contain any row where "john" is present.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `str_detect` with `filter`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(str_detect(first_name, 'john'))
```